# How to solve ODE by using greens function with Bessel equation result

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, bessel-functions, greens-function

Use Green's function to reduce to quadratures the solution of
\begin{equation}
 xy''+y'+xy=R(x), ~~~~~~~~~~ u(0) \;\text{finite}, u(b)=0,
\end{equation}
on $0\leq x\leq b,$ where $b=y_{0,1}=0.89377$ is the first zero of the $Y_0$ Bessel function and $R$ is bounded on $[0,b].$ You may use the result that the Wronskian of the ${J_0}$ and $Y_0$ Bessel function is $W(j_0,Y_0;x)=J_0(x)Y_0'(x) -J_0'(x)Y_0(x)=\dfrac{2}{(\pi x)}$ [There is a subtle difference to the standard case here, due to $x=0$ being a singular point. Is it not necessary that one of your linearly independent solutions of the homogeneous equation vanish at $x=0?$ Instead, you require only that one solution be bounded there.]

My work so far:

\begin{eqnarray}
xy''+y'+xy&=&R(x) \nonumber\\
xy''+y'+xy&=&0\nonumber\\
\text{let} ~y&=&x^n\implies y'=nx^{n-1} \nonumber\\
\implies y''&=&n(n-1)x^{n-2}\nonumber\\
n(n+1)+n+1&=&0\nonumber\\
n^2-n+n+1&=&0\nonumber\\
n^2+1&=&0\nonumber\\
n^2&=&-1.
\end{eqnarray}
How to continue?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your question, but use $\LaTeX$ to type it up. Also, you need to post what work you've done on the problem, or it's practically guaranteed we will close this question.

Comment: I know about properties of green theorem but question is like that  how to use bessel result at same time.

Comment: I'm commenting on the formatting of your question, which is abysmal. I'm not commenting on the content. On Math.SE we highly encourage you to use $\LaTeX$ to typeset your question, and you should also post whatever work you've done on it.

Comment: You need to add this to this question, not as a comment. And please add any work you've done to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: I've done into latex please resolve into solution

Comment: I've add short answer